# Progressive Loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a loop like that;

```
 for i in range(0,500):
```

But the rest of them takes more time. I want to split my loop for instance 5 steps. In the first step i want to run the first 100, at last, 401 to 500. But i don't want to write this loop five times.

Is there any short-way this kind of progressive run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a loop inside a loop:

```
for s in range(0, 500, 100):
    for i in range(s, s+100)):
        ...
```

Since in python indices start and 0 and the `range` is not inclusive of the last number this does, 0-99, 100-199, ..., 400-499.

Comment: Yes, You could also use a step argument on `range`, something like this: `for j in range(0, 500, 100): for i in range(j, j+100): ...`

Comment: Yes, I like that more.

Comment: How can you enhance your answer if the limit is 499? Because it is out of range.

Answer (score 0):

If time is what you are trying to trim, use [xrange()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange), it is MUCH faster, especially when dealing with large numbers:

```
for i in xrange(500):
```

Edit: This is for Python 2.x, not 3.x!

Comment: *If* he/she is using Python2.x. In Python3.x `xrange()` was renamed `range()`.

Comment: ahh yes very true, people need to specify, for some reason I automatically assume people are using 2.x.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't say `xrange()` is much faster than `range()`. I ran som test with `timeit` which showed that `xrange()` was around 5 % faster. The benefit rather comes from memory usage.

Comment: What range of values did you use? When you go up in the much higher ranges, you quickly see the time difference, as in factors of 10-100

Comment: I first tried in range of 100, but I tried it again in range of 10000. It varied between 4-8 % faster performance in favor of `xrange()`. Although, I'm measuring the time using list comprehensions, but that shouldn't make a huge difference.

Comment: I mean 10000 is still smaller range, try in the 1-2 million. I'm using it for ranges of 6-7 million and at that point its very much needed for saving time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120839/discussion-between-ted-klein-bergman-and-dhdavvie).